# Replace multiple characters by one character with regex

Tags: javascript, string

I have this string :

```
var str = '#this #is____#a test###__'
```

I want to replace all the character (#,_) by (#) , so the excepted output is :

```
'#this #is#a test#'
```

Note :
I did not knew How much sequence of (#) or (_) in the string

what I try :

I try to write :

```
var str = '#this #is__ __#a test###__'
str = str.replace(/[#_]/g,'#')
alert(str)
```

But the output was :

```
#this #is## ###a test#####
```

[my try online](http://jsfiddle.net/fnRcL/1330/)

I try to use the (*) for sequence But did not work :

```
var str = '#this #is__ __#a test###__'
str = str.replace(/[#_]*/g,'#')
alert(str)
```

so How I can get my excepted output ?

Comment: You are missing `+` in regex [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/fnRcL/1331/). `+` means 1 or more, so it will capture multiple characters instead of just 1

Comment: try this `str.replace(/[_]+/g, "").replace(/[#]{2,}/g, "#")`

Comment: it work as you said Mr  @Rajesh  thank you very much

Comment: May `replaceAll` will be efficient.

Answer (score 6):

A well written RegEx can handle your problem rather easily.
Quoting Mohit's answer to have a startpoint:

```
var str = '#this #is__ __#a test###__';
var formattedStr = str.replace(/[#_,]+/g, '#');
console.log( formattedStr );
```

Line 2:
Put in formattedStr the result of the replace method on str.
How does replace work? The first parameter is a string or a RegEx.
Note: RegExps in Javascripts are Objects of type RegExp, not strings. So writing

```
/yourRegex/
```

or

```
New RegExp('/yourRegex/')
```

is equivalent syntax.
Now let's discuss this particular RegEx itself.
The leading and trailing slashes are used to surround the pattern, and the g at the end means "globally" - do not stop after the first match.
The square parentheses describe a set of characters who can be supplied to match the pattern, while the + sign means "1 or more of this group".
Basically, ### will match, but also *#* or ***#*###**#**_#** will, because _ and # belong to the same set.
A preferred behavior would be given by using (#|_)+
This means "# or _, then, once found one, keep looking forward for more or the chosen pattern".
So ___ would match, as well as #### would, but __## would be 2 distinct match groups (the former being __, the latter ##).
Another problem is not knowing wheter to replace the pattern found with a _ or a #.
Luckily, using parentheses allows us to use a thing called capturing groups. You basically can store any pattern you found in temporary variabiles, that can be used in the replace pattern.
Invoking them is easy, propend $ to the position of the matched (pattern).
/(foo)textnotgetting(bar)captured(baz)/ for example would fill the capturing groups "variables" this way:

```
$1 = foo
$2 = bar
$3 = baz
```

In our case, we want to replace 1+ characters with the first occurrence only, and the + sign is not included in the parentheses! 
So we can simply

```
str.replace("/(#|_)+/g", "$1");
```

In order to make it work.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Your regex replaces single instance of any matched character with character that you specified i.e. `#`. You need to add modifier `+` to tell it that any number of consecutive matching characters (_,#) should be replaced instead of each character individually. `+` modifier means that 1 or more occurrences of specified pattern is matched in one go. You can read more about modifiers from this page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

```js
var str = '#this #is__ __#a test###__';
var formattedStr = str.replace(/[#_,]+/g, '#');
console.log( formattedStr );
```

Comment: Missing explanation. Please remember that you are answering for readers and not just OP

Comment: Thanks @Rajesh I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `+` to match one-or-more occurrences of the previous group.

```js
var str = '#this #is__ __#a test###__'
str = str.replace(/[#_]+/g,'#')
alert(str)
```