# Regular expression for exactly OR contains

Tags: java, regex

I want to send a location to Google Geocoding API, therefore I want to replace any space or comma in the text (as it can be received) with +.

For example, all those samples **should return Glentworth+Ireland**:

> Glentworth Ireland
>
> Glentworth,Ireland
>
> Glentworth, Ireland

I tried with: `place.replaceAll("/\\\\b ,/\\\\b|[ ,]", "+")`. But I still got in the latest case Glentworth++Ireland (where it's should be one plus only).

So the question is how can I replace " ," with plus (and just if `<space>,` not exist exact to replace the space/comma with plus) ?

(Or in other words, how can I be sure the place is ready to send as request to the API).

P.S. Of course, I can do it with to replaces, but not want!

Comment: `"/\\\\b ,/\\\\b|[ ,]"` are you trying to use `sed` syntax? You have `/` inside your regex which will be read as *literal* forward slashes, not as delimiting a search regex.

Comment: I don't understand the way you explain your requirements, but it looks like you just want `place.replaceAll("[, ]+", "+");`

Comment: I think you need `.replaceAll("\\s*,\\s*", "+")` or `.replaceAll("[,\\s]+", "+")`

Comment: @khelwood, THANK YOU! your soulution is works! (@Wiktor there's a bug, not replace only space with +)

Comment: [`.replaceAll("[,\\s]+", "+")` works](https://ideone.com/2myULn). Why do you use `/\\\\b ,/\\\\b`?

Comment: I don't know what is the relation between this post and the duplicate post?

Comment: **Duplicate of [How I can replace multiple character by one character in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446134/how-i-can-replace-multiple-character-by-one-character-in-javascript)**

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't agree is a duplicate, two different languages, and two different ways

Comment: @YCF_L The solution is universal across NFA regexes: **just add `+`** to match one or more occurrences. It is a purely **regex** issue. There is only 1 way. But you may of course use limiting quantifiers as well. It is still a matter of using a quantifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace any sequence of commas and spaces in your string with a single plus sign, you can do this:

```
place.replaceAll("[, ]+", "+")
```

`[, ]` is a character class containing comma and space, that means it will match either a comma or a space.

`+` means "the preceding item one or more times".

So `[, ]+` means "one or more occurrences of commas and/or spaces".

Comment: @VishwaRatna I've added more explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do it with two replaces: at first you replace any "," to " ", and next you replace all spaces to one plus.
If you want to do it with one replace, you can use `"[\,\s]\s*"`