# Replace special characters with "just one" underscore if in sequence

Tags: regex

I have a string where there can be spaces and special characters, how do i replace the spaces and special characters with only **one** underscore if they are in sequence.

I have tried `gsub(/[\W]/, '_')` but this replaces each special character with underscore.

```
Example string: "This is a sample string & example"
Current output: "This_is_a_sample_string___example"
Expected output: "This_is_a_sample_string_example"
```

Any help on how to fix this would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: Use a quantifier `\W+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird thanks for your reply but id did not fix the issue i still see the current output

Comment: I get these results https://regex101.com/r/xcyOyx/1

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: ah got it i had to put the + outside the square brackets like `[\W]+`.  I had initially tried with `[\W+]` my bad. if you can add your comment as an answer i can accept it.

Comment: I am using `gsub` function in `ruby`

Comment: @opensource-developer, Re "*i had to put the + outside the square brackets like `[\W]+`*", You misunderstood. You weren't being recommended `[\W]+`. When they said `\W+`, they meant `\W+`. The backslashed character classes (e.g. `\W`) don't need to be in a character class (`[]`).

Comment: @Thefourthbird The linked question is a potentially useful link for future visitors, but not an exact duplicate. Just because a question attracts similar answers doesn't mean the problem statement is the same. In this case, the question is about a different language, and would make a poor close target.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why do you keep trying to close a Ruby question for a *related* JavaScript question? The question is *not* an exact duplicate, and the answers are language-specific.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs It is a **regex** question, and the quantifiers are the same in these NFA regex engines.  OP has no issues with the Ruby code (`gsub` is used correctly).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The *solution* is about quantifiers, not the question. Therefore, closing as a duplicate is plainly wrong. Secondly, AFAIK JavaScript doesn't use the Onigmo engine, which can lead to a different solution space in each language. Linking the questions is fine, but they are *not* duplicates in the intended sense.

Comment: This question is about using a quantifier, for which there are enough duplicates to be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `/\W+/` to Match Sequential Non-Word Characters

Use the [`\W` metacharacter](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) with the `+` quantifier to match one or more sequential non-word characters. The [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) replacement text will only be used once for each whole match, not for each character in the match. For example:

```
'This is a sample string & example'.gsub /\W+/, '_'
#=> "This_is_a_sample_string_example"
```

There are certainly other ways to do this, but this solution fits your posted use case.

Comment: Please reclose with [Replace multiple characters by one character with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446134/replace-multiple-characters-by-one-character-with-regex). No need of re-answering these basic regex, close to typo, questions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The question you're linking to is a related (but not duplicate) question about a different language, and thus makes a poor close target.

Comment: Regex `+` quantifier is the same across these non-POSIX regex libraries. OP has no issues with  the Ruby code.